# open plugin perspective with windowbuilder eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, windowbuilder

Is it possible to open a perspective of a plugin in with googels windowbuilder (d2wbpro) ?
Or are there any other ways to customize the whole perspective ?

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Windowbuilder is a swt/swing editor. It doesn't support eclipse related UIs such View, Perspective and so on. There is a really good tutorial, how to define a new perspective [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html).